# Large network figures

Tags: r, plot, network-programming, nodes, igraph

I am using R igraph to generate a network figure. I am using the following code and all nodes are cluttered. Any suggestion to improve the figures? This network has 307 interactions between the nodes. Thanks

```
V(graph)[c("DISC1","GSK3B", "NRG1", "BDNF","GRM5", "DLG2", "DTBP1", "1433E", "NMDE1", "CNTP2")]$label.color <-"blue" 
      l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(graph, niter=5000, area=vcount(graph)^4*10)


  g <- plot(graph, layout=l, 
          edge.arrow.size=0.5, 
          vertex.label.cex=0.75, 
          vertex.label.family="Helvetica",
          vertex.label.font=2,
          vertex.shape="circle", 
          vertex.size=1, 
          vertex.color="black", 
          edge.width=0.5)
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gwNN.png)

Comment: Since you do not provide your data nor even a picture of the plot you have so far, it is pretty hard for anyone to make a suggestion..

Comment: @G5W Please find the figure, included it below the question. Thanks